# Switching the bounds of the potential difference integral

Tags: potential, calculus

$V = V_C-V_B = - \int_B^C \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{s}$

My teacher switched the bounds of this integral and put an additional minus sign into it. I couldn't understand because when we change the bounds, the direction of $d\mathbf{s}$ will change too. So there will be 3 minus signs in total: from the dot product, from the bounds and the additional minus sign. Could you explain what $d \mathbf{s}$ refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More rigorously, you must define $\vec{s}$ before you define $d\vec{s}$.

For example, $\vec{s} = cos(t)\hat{i} + sin(t)\hat{j}$ and $\vec{E}=
\hat{i}$, 
then $$d\vec{s} = d(cos(t))\hat{i} + d(sin(t))\hat{j} = [-sin(t)\hat{i} + cos(t)\hat{j}] dt$$
and the integral may be
$$
\int_A^{B} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_0^{\pi} \hat{i} \cdot [-sin(t)\hat{i} + cos(t)\hat{j}] dt = \int_0^{\pi} -sin(t)dt
$$
Changeing A B to B A would be 
$$
\int_B^{A} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{\pi}^{0} \hat{i} \cdot [-sin(t)\hat{i} + cos(t)\hat{j}] dt = \int_{\pi}^{0} -sin(t)dt
$$

So $d\vec{s}$ doesn't change if you change bounds.

Comment: Is there any general definition for S in real life problems?

Comment: In real problems where it is not defined for you explicitly, I think people do try to align the direction of $d\vec{s}$ to that of the lower to upper bound. This problem usually only exhibit itself when people try to do some mathematical tricks with them and have to invert the bounds.